# how to export to csv/excel using vaadin grids?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

In Vaadin 14+, I'm creating grids and would like the users to have a stable/easy way to export the grid's contents to csv or, preferablly, Excel. To do so, I was surprised that Vaadin does not appear to provide this functionality, and so one has to use 3rd party developer plugins (such as https://vaadin.com/directory/component/exporter/overview). However, these plugins have numerous bugs (eg can't export grids with date values correctly to Excel etc.). Is there a recommended approach in Vaadin 14 to supporting what I would assume is a highly requested feature of any web-based grid widget?

Comment: Related: [*Dynamically-created content for download without writing a file on server-side in Vaadin Flow web app*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60822729/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for plugins (called *add-ons* in Vaadin).

## `DataProvider`

You need to understand that a [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.18/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) widget is for *presentation*, not data storage.

Each `Grid` object is backed by a [`DataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.18/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/DataProvider.html), which is responsible for accessing the data store. The data to be displayed in a `Grid` might come from some objects in memory, or from a data feed, or from the results of a database query, or from some other source. Following the design principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), the `Grid` class is concerned only with displaying data, not managing data access. The `DataProvider` interface is concerned with managing data access, not displaying data. So `Grid` and `DataProvider` work together.

For a limited number of data objects based all in memory, we can use a [`ListDataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.18/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html) implementation of `DataProvider`. This list data provider can be built automatically for us when we pass a collection of our data objects.

So you do not export data from the `Grid` object. Instead, you want to listen for changes to the `DataProvider`, and then offer exporting data obtained through that data provider.

There is no built-in export feature in `DataProvider`. You can write your own export feature while drawing upon the data made available in the `DataProvider` implementation. You can choose between many Java-based libraries to assist in writing data files for your exported data. In the code shown below, we use the *Apache Commons CSV* library for writing tab-delimited or comma-separated values.

Here is a complete example app.

[image]

We have a simple `Person` class to hold a name and a phone number.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Person
{
    //---------------|  Member vars  |--------------------------------
    private String name, phone;


    //---------------|  Constructors  |--------------------------------

    public Person ( String name , String phone )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    //---------------|  Accessors  |--------------------------------

    public String getName ( ) { return this.name; }

    public void setName ( String name ) { this.name = name; }

    public String getPhone ( ) { return this.phone; }

    public void setPhone ( String phone ) { this.phone = phone; }


    //---------------|  Object  |--------------------------------


    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return getName().equals( person.getName() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getName() );
    }
}
```

This is an entire Vaadin 14.1.18 app that generates 4 `Person` objects as a sample data set. Those objects are fed to a `Grid`, which produces a `ListDataProvider` for our convenience.

We have a text field for editing the phone number of the selected `Person` object represented in the grid.

And we have an export button which uses the [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to write out a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. Notice the key line where we access the data items from the `ListDataProvider`. First we cast the data provider to `ListDataProvider`, then we extract a `Collection` of all the `Person` objects stored within. [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) provides type-safety, and empowers the compiler to know that the data provider contains `Person` objects.

```
Collection < Person > persons = ( ( ListDataProvider < Person > ) grid.getDataProvider() ).getItems();
```

Complete Vaadin 14.1 app code follows.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.GridSingleSelectionModel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Input;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.ListDataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
//@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
@CssImport ( "./styles/shared-styles.css" )
@CssImport ( value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    Grid < Person > grid;
    TextField phoneField;
    Button phoneSaveButton, exportButton;

    public MainView ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        List < Person > personList = new ArrayList <>( 4 );
        personList.add( new Person( "Alice" , "555.123.1234" ) );
        personList.add( new Person( "Bob" , "555.688.4787" ) );
        personList.add( new Person( "Carol" , "555.632.2664" ) );
        personList.add( new Person( "David" , "555.543.2323" ) );

        // Create a grid bound to the list
        grid = new Grid <>();
        grid.setItems( personList );
        grid.addColumn( Person :: getName ).setHeader( "Name" );
        grid.addColumn( Person :: getPhone ).setHeader( "Phone" );
        GridSingleSelectionModel < Person > singleSelect = ( GridSingleSelectionModel < Person > ) grid.getSelectionModel();
        singleSelect.setDeselectAllowed( false );
        singleSelect.addSingleSelectionListener( singleSelectionEvent -> {
                    Optional < Person > personOptional = singleSelectionEvent.getSelectedItem();
                    if ( personOptional.isPresent() )
                    {
                        this.phoneField.setValue( personOptional.get().getPhone() );
                    }
                }
        );

        phoneField = new TextField( "Phone:" );

        phoneSaveButton = new Button( "Update phone on person " );
        phoneSaveButton.addClickListener(
                ( ClickEvent < Button > clickEvent ) -> {
                    Optional < Person > personOptional = ( ( GridSingleSelectionModel < Person > ) grid.getSelectionModel() ).getSelectedItem();
                    if ( personOptional.isEmpty() )
                    {
                        Notification.show( "First, select a person in list." );
                    } else
                    {
                        Person person = personOptional.get();
                        person.setPhone( phoneField.getValue() );
                        grid.getDataProvider().refreshItem( person );
                    }
                }
        );

        exportButton = new Button( "Export" );
        exportButton.setEnabled( false );
        exportButton.addClickListener(
                ( ClickEvent < Button > clickEvent ) -> {
                    String fileName = "Persons_" + Instant.now().toString() + ".csv";
                    final String fileNamePath = "/Users/basilbourque/" + fileName;
                    try (
                            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( Paths.get( fileNamePath ) ) ;
                            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter( writer , CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader( "Name" , "Phone" ) ) ;
                    )
                    {
                        Collection < Person > persons = ( ( ListDataProvider < Person > ) grid.getDataProvider() ).getItems();
                        for ( Person person : persons )
                        {
                            csvPrinter.printRecord( person.getName() , person.getPhone() );
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( IOException e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Tell user.
                    Notification.show( "Exported to file in your home folder: " + fileName );
                }
        );
        grid.getDataProvider().addDataProviderListener( dataChangeEvent -> {
            exportButton.setEnabled( true );
        } );


        // Arrange
        this.add( grid , phoneField , phoneSaveButton , exportButton );
    }
}
```

By the way, Apache Commons CSV offers several varieties of file formats. Usually, the best would be the standard format defined in RFC 4180. But you mentioned Microsoft Excel, for which the library supports that variant. See the [`CSVFormat`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/index.html) class.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. This is perfect. One question though: this code would produce a file that is stored on the server. How can the clicking of the "export" button instead trigger a download to the user's local computer? (Ideally, it would prompt the user to chose a "save as" location so that the user could chose the location and file name.) 2nd bonus: can this file creation+download occur directly in a streaming fashion, so that the file is never created on the server, but instead is piped directly to the user's download? This would make a difference primarily for large files.)

Comment: @JonathanSylvester To keep narrowly-focused as Questions and Answers should be on Stack Overflow, I posted and answered another such Question: [*Dynamically-created content for download without writing a file on server-side in Vaadin Flow web app*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60822729/642706)

Comment: In case it helps, here's a video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgY-Sgf_iVI